# How to get image from facebook album using fb android sdk from a default account not the user's own account?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

My intention is that the app will use its own account to access FB, ie NOT the phone user's account and then download image from that default account's album to mobile.

And also user will not see any authentication or login dialogue. When user press a button an image will be downloaded from facebook album and stored in the user's mobile's sd card.

Does this possivle and if possible can anybody show me some path to achieve this or any tutorial.

I can get image from user's fb album after user logged in , but i want to get it from a default account that i have provided with the app and user does't have to login only download image.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to login/authenticate with a default account.  However, if it is stuff like images that you are fetching, you can make the default account's privacy setting for the items you want downloaded to be public so that you can download the images without having to authenticate the user.